# Calling initializeApp on refresh deleting the auth token stored in localstorage

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase to build a browser based app. I'm having this piece of code that is called when the page loads,

```
this._app = initializeApp({
  apiKey: this._apiKey,
  authDomain: `${this._projectId}.firebaseapp.com`,
  projectId: this._projectId,
  storageBucket: `${this._projectId}.appspot.com`,
  messagingSenderId: this._senderId,
  appId: this._appId
});

this._db = getFirestore(this._app);
```

Then I've a `login` method that uses `browserLocalPersistence` as below,

```
async login(email, password) {
  const auth = getAuth();
  await setPersistence(auth, browserLocalPersistence);
  return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
}
```

When I login first I see the token is successfully stored in localstorage. On refreshing the page I see the token is removed from localstorage and I think this is happening due to `initializeApp`. How can I keep the token persistent in localstorage?

Comment: Do you have any `onAuthStateChanged` observer? Does it log the user after refresh or null?

Comment: No I don't have one

Comment: In most cases there is no need to call `setPersistence` yourself, as the defaults should persist the user settings already. Instead, use `onAuthStateChanged` to [get the currently signed in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) once the page is reloaded.

Comment: Does the onAuthStateChange called on refresh? The default email/password stores the token in local storage?